# What does push "route 0.0.0.0" do in the OpenVPN server.conf file?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, openvpn, gateway

I am wondering what is the role of `push "route 0.0.0.0"` in `/etc/openvpn/server.conf`. In fact, I had a `push "route 0.0.0.0 "` line (notice the space at the end) in my server.conf file, and I had to comment it out in order to gain access to my server-side LAN and to the Internet through the VPN connection. I am assuming it is a catch-all rule for all network traffic that does not comply with other routes... Is that what it is? And if so, what's the gateway then?

Comment: The `default` route is encoded as `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: @dirkt And what would be the gateway for that default route?

Comment: None (which would be a bug), unless it's specified somewhere else in the configuration with `route-gateway`.

Comment: @dirkt Would `push "redirect-gateway def1"` do the job? It is the only mention of `gateway` I can find in my server.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `push "redirect-gateway def1"`, you are already pushing the default route (in the form of two `/1` address ranges), with the correct gateway (the VPN server).

So that already does what you'd think `push "route 0.0.0.0"` would do, except it didn't miss the gateway option.

Answer (score 0):

I’ll just quote [the manual](http://openvpn.net/man.html):

> **--route network/IP [netmask] [gateway] [metric]**
>       Add route to routing table after connection is established. Multiple routes can be specified. Routes will be automatically torn down in reverse order prior to TUN/TAP device close.
>
> This option is intended as a convenience proxy for the **route(8)** shell command, while at the same time providing portable semantics across OpenVPN's platform space.
>
> **netmask** default -- 255.255.255.255
>
> **gateway** default -- taken from **--route-gateway** or the second parameter to **--ifconfig** when **--dev** tun is specified.
>
> The default can be specified by leaving an option blank or setting it to "default".
>
> The **network** and **gateway** parameters can also be specified as a DNS or /etc/hosts file resolvable name, or as one of three special keywords:
>
> **vpn_gateway** -- The remote VPN endpoint address (derived either from **--route-gateway** or the second parameter to **--ifconfig** when **--dev** tun is specified).
>
> **net_gateway** -- The pre-existing IP default gateway, read from the routing table (not supported on all OSes).
>
> **remote_host** -- The **--remote** address if OpenVPN is being run in client mode, and is undefined in server mode.

As you can see, specifying the next hop is optional. Your server configuration most likely implicitly pushes either `route-gateway`, `ifconfig`, or both.